# imported UserFilter as urls.py in django

Tags: python, django

I made a filter form for my website, but inside
url.py
When I write:
from mysite.search.filter import UserFilter
Do not get and do not accept
What to do
Code:

```
from mysite.search.filters import UserFilter
url(r'^search/$', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=UserFilter, 
template_name='search/user_list.html'), name='search'),
```

error :
No module named 'mysite.search'

Comment: Please post *code*, not *images* of code, see [ask]

Comment: please help me!

Comment: from mysite import UserFilter

Or if the mysite is root than from search.filters import UserFilter

Comment: you probably should write `search.filters`, since `mysite` is probably the root.